# PHP require_once not working: no such file in directory

Tags: php, heroku, phpunit

I am having an issue with paths when testing the application using PHPUnit to test. I have a test called `UserControllerTest`:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/../../Controllers/UserController.php";

class UserControllerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    private $controller;

    protected function setUp() {
        $this->controller = new UserController();
    }

    public function testThatCanGeneratePromoCode() {
        $promoCode = $this->controller->generatePromoCode();

        $this->assertEquals(20, strlen($promoCode));
    }
}
```

Which is testing `UserController` class:

```
<?php

require_once "../config/DbConnection.php";
require_once "../Model/ConsumerModel.php";
require_once "../Managers/UtilManager.php";

class UserController {

    private $dbh;
    private $utilManager;
    private $model;

    /**
     * UserController constructor.
     * @param null|ConsumerModel $model
     * @internal param $dbh
     */
    public function __construct(ConsumerModel $model = null) {
        $this->dbh = new DbConnection();
        $this->utilManager = new UtilManager();
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function generatePromoCode() {
        $length = 20;
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }
}
```

And I keep getting this error when I run the test:
`PHP Warning:  require_once(../config/DbConnection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\MrDan\Documents\code\twinportrait-api\Controllers\UserController.php on line 3`

However, if I use `require_once __DIR__ .` for all the required files in the `UserController` class, the test works. But the deployment on Heroku fails throwing a `500 status code`. Any suggestion of how to fix this issue?

This is my project structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: The folder where the script is executing isn't necessarily where the script file exists.... you're executing the test in your test folder, so that relative path will be relative to the test folder, not to the folder where the UserController file exists

Comment: @MarkBaker Ok I understand, but what would be a solution?

Comment: See below @DanielOMensah

Comment: Start by looking at the logs on heroku to see what is causing that 500 error

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out what path you have to begin with. First

```
var_dump( realpath( __DIR__ . '/../..' ) );
```

This will show you what parent directory you are trying to navigate to. Then correct the path to `config/DbConnection.php` from there.

The `__DIR__` magic constant gives you the same directory that the file it exists in lives in. `realpath` will return `false` on an invalid path. If the above returns `false`, it means your webserver user does not have directory permissions to access that folder, because the folder two levels down should definitely exist in your case. If that is the case, you need to `chmod` the config folder. Otherwise your path string is off.